# How to scan through an InputFile?

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner

Currently I have a while loop that reads through an input file simply named "input". This input file contains numbers, such as "1 2 3 4" that represent something that is irrelevant to my question. To receive the number "1", I use `scanner.nextInt();` If this is the correct way to receive 1, I am stuck on how to receive the other numbers 2 3 4.

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){

    int firstnum = scanner.nextInt();
    // How do I get the second, third, and fourth number?

    //It is not guaranteed that I will be given exactly 4 numbers, but I will be given at least that many.
```

Comment: Do you have line-break characters inside your file?

Answer (score 1):

Just continue the loop and accumulate the numbers you encounter, e.g., to a list:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: What would I do if the input being read contains Ints and also Strings?

Comment: @SarahQ. is there any pattern to the input file, or do you need to analyze it as you go?